# optimize the below code for show hide hover

Tags: jquery, optimization

I want to optimize the below code for *n* `<li>`.

When hovering on the two `<li>`s the corresponding "Details 1" and "Details 2" are being displayed, but I don't want to rewrite the same function again and again for further `<li>`s in case there are more than 2, so I need help in optimizing the code.

```
 <li id="placePolicy"><a href="#">PLACE A POLICY</a> </li>
 <li id="growBussiness"><a href="#">GROW MY BUSINESS</a></li>

 <div id="Details1">qwrqwrqwre</div>
 <div id="Details2">qwrwqrwrqwrqrq</div>


  $(function() {
      $('#placePolicy').hover(function() { 
       $('#Details1').show(); 
      }, function() { 
    $('#Details1').hide(); 
     });
     });
      $(function() {
          $('#Details1').hover(function() { 
       $('#Details1').show();   
         }, function() { 
          $('#Details1').hide(); 
        });
           });  


           $(function() {
          $('#growBussiness').hover(function() { 
               $('#Details2').show(); 
            }, function() { 
              $('#Details2').hide(); 
         });
        });
           $(function() {
           $('#Details2').hover(function() { 
              $('#Details2').show();   
         }, function() { 
             $('#Details2').hide(); 
        });
            });     `
```